# CMS для сайта с 300+ поддоменов

Tags: cms, администрирование, перенос, tilda

**Дано:**
Сайт с 300+ поддоменами на регионы.
Обычные лендниги на тильде, у всех один дизайн.

**Цель:** При изменении информации на сайте - она меняется на всех поддоменах.

Решили переносить сайт на CMS.

**Вопрос:** исходя из вводных, какая CMS наиболее безпроблемна для достижения цели? Интеграций кроме CRMки не будет.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какой контент и информация общие/разные у этих сайтов?Предположу – общий дизайн, статика и страницы описания фирмы, но разные цены и контактные данные?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, универсального решения нет. Рассмотрим популярные подходы:

### WordPress Network

У ВордПресса есть встроенная поддержка много-сайтовости (у кого есть перевод получше?), т.н WP Network, однако, судя по отзывам, его сложно настраивать, особенно по части SSL-сертификатов для разных доменов.

Узнать больше можно здесь:

- [wpbeginner.com](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/)
- [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/)

### Drupal

В Drupal тоже есть поддержка много-сайтовости, но отзывы говорят о сложностях её поддержки, т.к Drupal во всём полагается на многочисленные плагины и он регулярно обновляется с большими изменениями.

Узнать больше можно здесь:

- [ostraining.com](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-multi-sites/)
- [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/multisite-drupal)

### Decoupled CMS и Headless CMS

Это не конкретные CMS, а такие современные подходы разделения и "обезглавливания" CMS, при котором классической CMS отдаётся лишь роль API сервера, а фронтэнд пишется отдельный. Эти способы отличаются повышенной гибкостью в настройке и безопасностью по сравнению с классическим Coupled CMS подходом и особенно полезны при наличии других клиентов вроде мобильных приложений, но также иногда эти методики советуют как способ реализации мульти-сайтовости. Из минусов – нужно самим заботиться о серверах и фронтэнде, и по сути это не сильно лучше написания сайта полностью с нуля.

Больше информации об этих подходах:

- [npgroup.net](https://www.npgroup.net/services/development/headless-decoupled-content-management-systems/)
- [contentstack.com](https://www.contentstack.com/cms-guides/decoupled-cms)

### SDL Tridion

Есть CMS уровня энтерпрайз под названием [Tridion от компании SDL](https://www.sdl.com/software-and-services/tridion-dx/tridion-sites.html) популярная у крупных фирм и заточенная для удобной работы со множеством языков и доменов. Недостаток – эта CMS далеко не бесплатная.